# How can I show that $f\mapsto f'$ is a closed map?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, solution-verification, closed-map, closed-graph

> Let $X=C^1([0,1])$ and $Y=C([0,1])$ both equipped with $\|f\|=\max |f|$. Then consider $$D:X\rightarrow Y:~~f\mapsto f'$$
> I want to check that $D$ is a closed map.

By definition we need to show that the graph is closed, i.e. $G(D)=\{(f,Df):f\in X\}$ is closed in $X\times Y$. So let $(f_n,Df_n)\rightarrow (f,g)\in X\times Y$. I want to show that $(f,g)\in G(D)$ i.e. that $Df=g$. Now $$\begin{align}\|Df-g\|&=\|Df-Df_n+Df_n-g\|\\&\leq\|Df-Df_n\|+\|Df_n-g\|\\&\leq\|D\|\|f-f_n\|+\|Df_n-g\| \end{align}$$ Now we know $$f_n\rightarrow f \Leftrightarrow \|f_n-f\|\rightarrow 0$$$$Df_n\rightarrow g\Leftrightarrow \|Df_n-g\|\rightarrow 0$$so it remains to check that $||D||<\infty$. $$\|D\|=\sup_{\|f\|\leq 1}\|Df\|=\sup_{\|f\|\leq 1}\|f'\|=\sup_{\|f\|\leq 1}\max|f'|$$  but now since $f'$ is continuous and $[0,1]$ is compact we know that the maximum exists so let me denote $\max|f'|=M$, then $$\|D\|=\sup_{\|f\|\leq 1}M=M<\infty$$ hence as $n\rightarrow \infty$ we get $\|Df-g\|=0$ and therefore $D$ is closed.

Is this correct?

Comment: $D$ is not bounded : example $f_n(x) = x^n$. The problem is that your constant $M$ is dependent on $f$...

Comment: If you know $||D||$ exists then you already know $D$ is continuous and that the graph is closed!

Comment: @badinmaths ah okey I see what you mean. So this way will not work right?

Comment: @FShrike but $\|D\|$ does not need to be bounded or what do you want to tell me?

Comment: @user1294729 No, I don’t think $X$ is Banach so the closed graph theorem doesn’t apply, closedness won’t imply continuity

Comment: @FShrike sorry I'm now really lost. It isn't continuous you are right. But it still needs to be closed. And I don't understand your last comment will you say me $\|D\|$ exists?

Comment: I was saying, $\|D\|$ doesn't need to exist. Badinmaths' comment shows $\|D\|$ doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to adapt the proof of the following classic theorem

> If $(f_n)$ converges pointwise towards $f$ and $f_n'$ converges uniformally towards $g$ then $f$ is $C^1$ and $f' = g$

Let $t \geq 0$

$(f(t)-f(0))-(f_n(t)-f_n(0)) = \int_0^t f'(s)ds - \int_0^t f_n'(s)ds$

And $n \to \infty$ gives :

$0 = \int_0^t f'(s)ds - \int_0^t g(s)ds$  (since $f_n'$ converges uniformally towards $g$)

Which gives the result by differentiating the equality